# Not Getting Core Motion to Display Accelerometer Data in UI

Tags: ios, swift, core-motion

I'm attempting to show accelerometer data in a UI using Swift. I was following some examples on http://nshipster.com/cmdevicemotion/ and have tried using their method of rotating an image and also just displaying the x accel data as a label but neither my imageView nor my Label are transforming/updating with any data. I'm building and running on my iPhone 6 (not simulator).

```
import UIKit
import CoreMotion

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let manager = CMMotionManager()

    if manager.accelerometerAvailable {

        manager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.01

        manager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {
            [weak self] (data: CMAccelerometerData!, error: NSError!) in

            let rotation = atan2(data.acceleration.x, data.acceleration.y) - M_PI

            self?.image.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(rotation))

            self?.label.text = String(format: "%.2f", data.acceleration.x)
        }


    }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a local `CMMotionManager` to `viewDidLoad()`, but you need a global `CMMotionManager` in order for it to be available inside your Queue. Try instantiating `manager` above `viewDidLoad()`, like this:

```
import UIKit

import CoreMotion

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!

let manager = CMMotionManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let manager = CMMotionManager()

    if manager.accelerometerAvailable {

        manager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.01

        manager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {
            [weak self] (data: CMAccelerometerData!, error: NSError!) in

            let rotation = atan2(data.acceleration.x, data.acceleration.y) - M_PI

            self?.image.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(rotation))

            self?.label.text = String(format: "%.2f", data.acceleration.x)
        }
    }
}
```